# Concurrent 5 users connection to VM using bastion

Tags: azure, azure-bastion

I want to have 5 concurrent logins to my Window VM. I have set up the bastion service and can log in through admin as well as as an invited user. but the issue is am not able to log in as multiple users at one time.

But in [bastion instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/configuration-settings#instance) it has stated that bastion can have 25 concurrent RDP sessions.

> [image]

And they also stated that we can create custom ports for connection. I did create Inbound for 6002 but I am not able to create it through bastion as it says "The network connection to the Bastion Host appears unstable."

> [image]

I even tried creating 4 instances but still got the same issue.

```
VM details:
Operating system: Windows (Windows 10 Pro)
Size: Standard B2ms (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)
```

> Bastion Details:
>
> [image]

Comment: Check this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185391/concurrent-azure-bastion-sessions>

Answer (score 0):

Set the inbound and outbound port and expose the 22 port Number. Make sure your IP is whitelisted on azure devops VM. So you can able to access. Check the telnet on your machine (tenet IP 22). If telnet abort the connection then your IPs are not whitelisted.